# Card game - creating card Listener

Tags: libgdx, sprites, touch

I am making a card game where there are 21 cards on hand and 2 options from where user can draw cards to his hand and throw a card from hand.
[image]

**I am new** on game development and I'm following the principle of MVC.
Till now in my game I have a `InputHandler` class that handel the input. `GameWorld` and `GameRender` are two class which controll the game logic and render the game respectively. Both of these class are called by `GameScreen` class which extends Screen.

My question is how should I implement the **touchListener to these cards.** They are now just `sprites` and I have used `texture Packer` to create a `spriteSheet`

Doing research i have found that `Stage` and `Actor` are the things that I am looking for. Reading on **wiki** I found that these are useful to create menus. I've also read that working with stage and Actor is  complex for **creating game environment and follow the rule of MVC.**

So, please anyone could guide me a way from where should I need to move forward. This is the very basic move that I need to move but I know if I did wrong here, i have to pay much more later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a listener to each of these cards if they are actors.

You can create and enum with each card:

```
public enum Cards{

     ACE_HEART("ACE_HEART.png"),
     2_HEART("2_HEART.png"),
     3_HEART("3_HEART.png");
     //etc

    private final String name;
    Cards(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public int getValue() { return name; }
}
```

and you can create a class:

```
public class Card extends Actor{
    float width, height;
    Sprite cardSprite;

    public Card(Cards cardType){
        cardSprite = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(cardType.getValue())));
        this.width = cardSprite.getWidth();
        this.height = cardSprite.getHeight();
    }
}
```

For example we have a Set with these cards (so they're unique):

```
Set<Card> allCards = CREATE AND ADD ALL OF THE CARDS

//assign listeners
for(Card card : allCards)
    card.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            Gdx.app.log("Clicked card at", x + "   " + y);
        }
    });

// now create a list for the player
Set<Card> playersHand = new SomeSet<>();

// we take 10 random cards to his hand:
while(playersHand.size() < 10)
    playersHand.add(allCards.get(new Random().nextInt(allCards.size() - 1));




public void render(){
    batch.begin();

    for(Card card : playersHand)
        card.draw(batch, posx, posy); // you can increment posX with each iteration
    batch.end();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't how you want to implement what I gonna say, but in most 2d game engines we have something called `TouchListener` (or in general term  `EventListener`) which can assigned to your card sprite (and many things else) and tell how should your game card handle touches.

I can bring you a piece of code which is for a Game Card that I wrote in cocos2d-x engine. I hope it clarify your understanding.

```
auto gameCardTouchListener = EventListenerTouchOneByOne::create();
auto allCards = deckList->GetAllCards();
for(int i=0; i<  allCards.size(); i++) // Assign a copy of touch listener to each card
    addEventListenerWithSceneGraphPriority(gameCardTouchListener->clone(), allCards[i]);
///
gameCardTouchListener ->onTouchBegan = [this](Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    // onTouchBegan Call for All touch listeners ( in some sequence) when
    // player start to touch screen.
    // Here we check which listener ( and It's related game card) handle it ?!
    auto myGameCard = static_cast<GameCard*>(event->getCurrentTarget());
    Point touchLocation = touch->getLocation();
    If ( /*Touch is over my card, I handle it*/ ) {
        ...
        return true; // I decide to capture this touch
    }
    return false; // Let some card else check this touch. Not mine;
}
///
gameCardTouchListener ->onTouchMoved= [this](Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    // What should happen when touch is moving
    // Maybe I should move this card where player is touching
}
///
gameCardTouchListener ->onTouchEnded =
gameCardTouchListener ->onTouchCancelled = [this](Touch* touch, Event* event)
{
    // What should happen when touch is over
}
```

Comment: the thing you post was great. I build up some idea from it. But if that was based on LibGdx, that would have been more great

Comment: @Asis In fact I didn't know LibGdx. I worked with many other platforms and I'm sure the idea is same everywhere for handling touch. It's best way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about touch listener, but I can help you with polling based input.
Here's how I'd handle input for the sprites

```
// assuming you have the input touch co-ordinates
if((touchX>= sprite.getPosition.x) && (touchX<= sprite.getPosition.x+sprite.getWidth()) && 
   (touchY>= sprite.getPosition.y) && (touchY<= sprite.getPosition.y+sprite.getHeight()))
   {

    //  Handle input
  }
```

Basically you need to check whether the touch point falls on the sprite's bounding rectangle
Based on the image above I might suggest you use a rectangle for a card's visible area and check for touches on that area